# libtiff.3.dylib: unknown required load command 0x80000022

Tags: c++, macos, osx-snow-leopard, shared-libraries

Has anyone found a fix for this? 
I read that it has something to do with new dylib format in Snow Leopard...

(This is the lib I get back from MacPorts.)

Thanks,
rui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to use that library with?  Chances are you have an old version of some build tool or app.  Have you updated all of your `MacPorts` installation?

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port -u upgrade outdated
```

EDIT: Based on your additional information, more questions:

You have `-I /sw/include` and `-L /sw/lib` which are standard locations for Fink, not MacPorts (`/opt/local/{include,lib}`).  In general, it's not a good idea to mix packages from Fink and MacPorts.  Are you actually pulling in anything from Fink?  If so, are all the Fink packages up-to-date?

If that doesn't resolve the issue, are you building on 10.5 and, if so, which 10.5? Or are you building on 10.6 an app targeted for 10.5 and 10.6?  Make sure you have the latest Xcode in either case.

EDIT: It is very difficult to diagnose problems like this based on sketchy information.  You say Leopard in your latest comment but then you say you are using the 10.6 SDK.  At this point, all I can suggest is that you make sure you have the latest Xcode updates installed and, if you want more help, update the question with a more complete description of what you are trying to do and exactly how and where you are trying to do it, including versions of tools like gcc, et al.  Good luck!

Comment: This is what I ran before compiling wxWidgets, GraphicsMagick and finally, my app. 

export CFLAGS="=-O -g -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -arch i386 -I/sw/include/ -m32" 

export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk,-L/sw/lib/ -m32" 

sudo port selfupdate sudo port clean -f installed sudo port uninstall -f installed sudo port install freetype zlib jpeg libpng tiff squish

Comment: That was a very good point, but even after recompiling everything with the correct prefixes (macports only) Leopard OS' still get 0x80000022. :( I'm adding the following to my compile flags -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk

Comment: My machine runs Snow Leopard. I'm compiling using the latest SDK 10.6 and  macosx-version-min to 10.5. I think my compilation is fine. I believe now that the problem lies in the libs provided by macports that seem to be only compiled for 10.6. When I bundle my app with these libs, the dylib load crashes with unknown instruction in Leopard (10.5). Thanks for your help diagnosing!

Comment: Yes, that would very likely be the problem.  You could probably trick MacPorts into building 10.5 targeted libraries on 10.6.  Or, if you have access to a 10.5 machine, it just might be easier to build everything there!

Answer (score 1):

We have this same problem whenever we try to run an executable compiled and linked on Snow Leopard *without* `-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5` and then try to run it on Leopard. Note the -isysroot setting is different than in your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The application was incorrectly built on OS X 10.6 machine for a 10.5 machine. The developer can fix this by considering three things:

1. Using the correct compiler parameters:
       gcc-4.2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk ...
2. Using the correct linker settings (setting environment variable before link command). This is required, so that the OS X 10.6 linker will not use the loader command 'LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY' (=0x80000022), because OS X 10.5 does not understand this command:

   export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5
   (or   setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5)

After this is fixed, one can check if the application was correctly built for OS X 10.5 by running 'otool':

otool -l binary

The correct binary should not contain any  'LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY' load commands (only 'LC_DYLD_INFO' commands).

(also see my blog article http://grauonline.de/wordpress/?p=71 )